# Appengine data over SSL?

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, https

This is simple, but there seems to be limited information on this topic.
I am working on a small backend for an iOS app which receives POST data (successfully).

I believe I have enabled https support (in the app, and on appengine), but how do I tell in AppEngine if the data really did come over HTTPS?

If it helps, I am connecting through the app on a https:// address and I am using:

> secure: always

in my app.yaml (from [here](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2008/10/announcing-https-support-for-appspotcom.html))

So far all I can do is 'presume' it is working.

Thanks again, SO rocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to verify that appengine is performing the way it's documented.

You could verify manually by going to the http url and should be redirected to https.

Programmatically you could check the request for the incoming scheme:
python/webapp: request.scheme
http://docs.webob.org/en/latest/reference.html#method-url

java: request.getScheme()
http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getScheme()